# How to parse multiple XML documents from a single stream?

Tags: python, xml

I've got a socket from which I'm reading XML data.  However, this socket will spit out multiple different XML documents, so I can't simply parse all the output I receive.

Is there a good way, preferably using the Python standard library, for me to parse multiple XML documents?  In other words, if I end up getting

```
<foo/>
<bar/>
```

then is there a way to either get multiple DOM objects or have a SAX parser simply work on such a stream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get separate documents, you'll need something to divide them; and if you have that, you can simply split the stream before you parse the individual documents.

Another possibility would be to wrap that into another document, so each XML document is actually a subdocument of a parent's you create (and wrap around) just for that purpose.