# Parsing and wrting XML files with Python at once

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I have a .txt File with lots of XML-Files in it.

So lets say:  `content.txt` is my file, and there are 40++ XML-"Files" in it. 
(No "real" files, of course, but tags with `<xml>....</xml><xml>...</xml>` and so on).

Now i want to create a parser in Python which reads the text-file, and writes every `<xml>...</xml>` in  a file. The name should be a `Tag-Data` inside each `<xml>....</xml>`.

What's the best solution for my problem?

I've read a lot about XML parsers, but nobody explains how to read AND write at the same time.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand. You know how to read, and you know how to write, what prevents you from reading and then writing? The only problem to solve here, is how to split a sequence of xml-documents into a sequence of those from a single file, since XML parsers allow only one document.

Comment: And the latter problem is partially solved here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4024838/770830 by wrapping the text document into a single parent tag... Unless you have some `<?xml?>` declaration.